# Automated configuration of Linux distributions using ansible without and with lower than required version of Python

Tags: bash, ansible

Looking for ideas of solution for the following predicament:

I'm currently in the middle of writing ansible script for management of all sorts of Linux distributions. Ranging from Debian 4 / CentOS 5, openSUSEs etc. to current Ubuntu's etc.
Due to the sheer range of unsupported Python versions on stock images of old distributions I'm stuck.

Problem: Use Ansible raw to upgrade Python to required by Ansible version
on all old distributions. Installing from sources seems to be out of option due to following reasons: 
 - no C compiler on stock images, 
 - dead repositories.

Frankly speaking, I have no idea how can it be accomplished even when I take in consideration using raw module. And due to the requirement as well as the number of instances, it needs to be done via script

I will appreciate any advice as I'm currently out of any options.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article that helped us in our case with some old CentOS 5 instances we had running: https://www.ansible.com/blog/using-ansible-to-manage-rhel-5-yesterday-today-and-tomorrow

```
---
- name: control remote legacy system
  hosts: legacy
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
  - script_vars.yml

  tasks:
  - name: create script on the fly to manage system
    template:
      src: manage_script.sh.j2
      dest: "/manage_script.sh”
    delegate_to: localhost
  - name: execute management script on target system
    script:
      manage_script.sh
  - name: execute raw command to upgrade system
    raw:
      yum upgrade -y
    become: yes
```

That article even lists how to do what I'm suggesting via the raw module. What we did is made a few bash scripts to achieve what we needed in bringing things up to spec ran them with raw and then continued on with normal ansible.

Doing this will allow you to affect changes on all instances just as if you were running the script on each one by hand. This should allow you to do what you need to make it so you can either upgrade these distros to non-EOL versions or bring them up to spec so they can communicate with the current versions of ansible.